# How to automatically change a Content type field value based on Date field?

Tags: 7, rules

I'm using Drupal 7, I have a content type, where I have two fields for project allocation:

1. Status(Active/Inactive)
2. End Date

If the "End date" is less than current date, then the "status field" should be Active(By Default, Status will be Active) and if it exceeds current date, then that particular "status field" value in Content type should automatically change to Inactive.

Now, how can I automatically change the field value without any Button trigger?

Comment: Do you want to do it when you save the node, or right when the end date field is updated?

Comment: If the end date is 31/12/19 and current date is 30/12/2019 and then status should automatically change to Inactive on 01/01/2020.

Comment: @naratouzu19 Do you want this to happen on a form during user interaction, or automatically in the background? When you say 'fields' this could refer to database fields or fields on a form so it's a little unclear as to what you need to happen.

Comment: I want it to happen in background, becoz i will have at least 100 data so whenever the current date exceeds the end date, status should change as Inactive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks both Jdrupal and gillarf above. 
I did something different here, but i used both of your logic.

First, i created a custom module and then i used hook_menu() function. In this hook_menu, i used a link and if i call that link then page callback function will execute.

In page callback function, i used dbquery to get the data from the DB and based on my condition, i change the data and then again i used db query to update the DB with new data.

Now, i fixed that link in drupal cron and set it to call the link by particuar time, so that it will execute everyday automatically.

That's it Thanks :)

Comment: Ok, well that's the same as my answer essentially, except that you aren't using rules actions, you are just hitting your function on cron using hook_menu

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to do this with some custom JS code.

You can do something like this:

```
$('.end-date-field').on('change', function () {
  var endDate = new Date($(this).val());
  if (endDate < Date.now()) {
    $('.status-field').val('inactive');
  }
});
```

This code is not 100% correct, but it can help you to get an idea of what you have to do.

Comment: Thanks, i will try it.

Comment: @Narutouzu19 Did it work?

Comment: I'm new to Drupal, all i know is to create custom modules. I'm working on creating Custom Js Code. I created a custom module with Hook_init() and in that i used drupal_add_js() but no use, not working :(

Comment: Have you seen this guide, https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/javascript-api/adding-javascript-to-your-theme-or-module?

Comment: I used drupal_add_js inline function, but the CT data is not modified based on the conditions we tried.

Comment: .end-date-field is the field machine name right? Like ".field_end_date"?

Comment: It's the HTML class of the input field.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't get it, how to know the html class of the input field

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102016/discussion-between-jdrupal-and-narutouzu19).

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this needs to happen behind the scenes rather than as a result of user interaction.

I suggest you write a custom rules action which runs on cron every 5 minutes (or whatever time period you are happy with). The rule should load all of the relevant nodes using a db_select query, loop through them, check the end date and update the status depending on the comparison result.

Check the video here by Johan Falk on how to create a rules action: https://drupalize.me/videos/creating-rules-action?p=1152

And info for db_select: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_select/7.x

If the site does not get a lot of traffic you might need to fire cron externally. You can use a service like uptime robot to do this (https://uptimerobot.com/), or you can get your server to do it. It will need to hit your cron endpoint.

Comment: Looping through all the nodes is a terrible way to do this. Instead you should use the Rules Scheduler to schedule a task that changes the status to inactive on the proper day. That will run once and only once, instead of checking the date on every node every 5 minutes.

Comment: Well it depends on how many nodes you expect to have. I've given a simple answer for what might be a simple use case, and it's true I have made an assumption that there are not many nodes.